# Validation Rule error message problem

Tags: validation-rule

I want to apply a validation rule for a price__c (data type is currency).My condition is that in remote app creation this field accept alphabet as a input and after click on save button it save only number in this field ,Now i want that if a user gave the input as alphabet it show error at this time how can i achieve this ? I am trying NOT(REGEX(TEXT(Price__c), '^[0-9;]*')) but its not working.

Comment: If your Price__c  is Currency - then it wont accept any other characters  than numbers to store in it by default.

Comment: When i take input as character  in accept the input but save only number so now my requirement is that at the time of user give the character as input it show error message

Comment: Your are trying get value for this field on VF ? if yes then try JavaScript Validation in VF page code itself.

Comment: http://th3silverlining.com/2010/03/02/visualforce-form-validation-enhanced/

Answer (score 0):

If your Price__c is Currency - then it wont accept any other characters than numbers to store in it by default.

May be this is cause (not sure) - But if you are using it somewhere else than Standard UI ---then try validation rule like this -

> NOT( ISNUMBER(TEXT(Price__c) ) )

Comment: Its not working in mobile (remote app)